# Open application in background without losing current window focus.  Fedora 17, Gnome 3

Tags: linux, gnome3

I'm running a script in the background which loads an image with `feh` depending on which application is currently in focus.  However, whenever the script opens the image, window focus is lost to feh.  I was able to circumvent this by using `xdotool` to switch back to the application that was originally in focus, but this introduces a short annoying period of time where the focus is switched from feh to the application.

**My question is this:** 
is there any way to launch `feh` in the background such that window focus is **NOT** lost?

System: Fedora 17, Gnome 3, Bash

Answer (score 1):

There is a configuration key for Metacity/Mutter that let's you disable focus on new windows launched from a terminal.

In Fedora 19 I found this by installing `dconf-editor` and locating the key under

```
org/gnome/desktop/wm/preferences/focus-new-windows
```

Setting this key from `smart` to `strict` should do the trick. You may find a similar key under `gonf-editor` and a different path with another system.

Comment: That's is exactly the option I was looking for. Unfortunately, it's currently broken: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/mutter/-/issues/2106